# How to make image fit window height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I'd like to set an image to match the height of my page minus top menu (50px). Also, I'm using `twitter bootstrap 3` and I know it's got `img-responsive` class, which is great and I'd like to use this class in combination with making the image `height=100%-50px`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your best bet would be using the css3 calc(), although I'm not entirely sure that subtracting a flat pixel value from a percentage would work. Please inform me (us) if it does! :)

Comment: @Applebough it does work, there are some issues with it though as the image is slightly deformed if I resize the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want combine percents with pixel you can use css3 property calc():

```
height: calc(100% - 50px);
```

Supported by IE9+